# How to call Struts Action from Jersey Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, struts, struts-1

I am Mobile App Developer so I don't know much about Web technologies.

Currently I am working on one project in which I am using Jersey for Mobile Web Service and main web site is in Struts1.

I want to call / pass some variables to Struts action from my web service but I don't know how can I call and pass some variable to that action.

Lets say this is url

> ```
> www.xyz.com/xyz/yyy/market/free/XYZAction.do.do?announce.id=1121&note=testing
> ```

of my action and I have to pass 2 parameter `announce.id` and `note`

Here is my code

```java
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("www.xyz.com/xyzWebservice/module/market/free/XYZAction.do");

String input = "{\"note\": \"This is note thank you\", "
              + "\"announce.id\":\"48298\", \"profil\":\"13855\", "
              + "\"idprofil\":\"13855\",\"portage\":\"false\"}";

// POST method
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("multipart/form-data")
                          .type("multipart/form-data")
                          .post(ClientResponse.class, input);


// check response status code
if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatus());
}


// display response
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
System.out.println(output + "\n");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `if it'sin web site is in "Struts1".` it's a mistery then why you tagged it struts2 :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios opps by mistake but it doesn't matter its Struts1 or 2 There is nothing big difference .. kind of iOS6 and iOS7 & 8... But Main aim is to get help not to correct by grammar..

Comment: No grammar involved... Struts1 and Struts2 are ***completely*** different. They share almost nothing apart the name, and Struts2 is another framework (WebWork2) migrated/renamed after the WebWork and the Struts communities joined. Also, Struts1 is dead from years. That said, the question barely (not) fits SO rules, good luck with that. BTW, you need to call URLs and send querystrings or post parameters, like calling a servlet.

Comment: @AndreaLigios but how can i call that particular action from my web service? To post parameter do i have to use JAVASCRIPT or is it possible to send form in Jersey?

Comment: Much better :) please define not working... What happens?

Comment: I'm a bit confused; it sure looks like you're trying to pass in JSON, whereas the URL you show is a GET request.